# ember-cli-migrator "Do not know how to import App" error

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-mirage

I'm migrating a custom made Ember project (I do not use a build system, but actually created my own grunt script). When I run ember-cli-migrate but I'm getting the following error:

```
Git Move Moving templates/users.hbs to app\templates\users.hbs
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App
Do not know how to import App

assert.js:86
  throw new assert.AssertionError({
        ^
AssertionError: {kind: var, declarations: [object Object], loc: null, type: Vari
ableDeclaration, comments: null} does not match field "init": Expression | null
of type VariableDeclarator
    at add (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-migrator\n
ode_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\types.js:525:28)
    at c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-migrator\node_m
odules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\types.js:539:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.defineProperty.value [as variableDeclarator] (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\
ast-types\lib\types.js:538:30)
    at Context.MigratorVisitorPrototype.visitAssignmentExpression (c:\Users\Dory
Z\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-migrator\lib\migrator-visitor.js:71
:67)
    at Context.invokeVisitorMethod (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\ember-cli-migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\path-visit
or.js:306:43)
    at Visitor.PVp.visitWithoutReset (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\ember-cli-migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\path-vis
itor.js:180:28)
    at NodePath.each (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-
migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\path.js:96:22)
    at visitChildren (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ember-cli-
migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\path-visitor.js:199:14)
    at Visitor.PVp.visitWithoutReset (c:\Users\DoryZ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\ember-cli-migrator\node_modules\recast\node_modules\ast-types\lib\path-vis
itor.js:188:16)
```

any help would be appreciatd..

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: yes...manually started to migrate everything over..frustrating..but what can you do?